# Sharing an observable becomes unicast when I add delay operator to a 2nd subscription

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

The following code works as expected:

```
    const source = interval(1000).pipe(
        take(5),    
        share()
  );

  source.subscribe(x => console.log('c1', x));
  setTimeout(() => {
    source.subscribe(x => console.log('c2', x));
  }, 2000);
```

producing the following output:
c1 0
c1 1
c1 2
c2 2
c1 3
c2 3
c1 4
c2 4

but when I change the second subscription to use delay(2000) instead of the setTimeout()
I get a different stream that is not shared.

```
    const source = interval(1000).pipe(
        take(5),    
        share()
  );

  source.subscribe(x => console.log('c1', x));

  source.pipe(delay(2000)).subscribe(x => console.log('c2', x));
```

Produces this output:

c1 0
c1 1
c1 2
c2 0
c1 3
c2 1
c1 4
c2 2
c2 3
c2 4

How do I get the second subscriber to use the shared stream?
I obviously don't understand fully how RX operators work under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `source.pipe(delay(2000))` is completely different to using `setTimeout()`. `delay()` operator will delay each emission from its source which means you're still making two subscriptions immediately.

What you probably wanted to do instead is this:

```
of(null)
  .pipe(
    delay(2000),
    switchMapTo(source),
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Or this should do the same thing:

```
concat(timer(2000), source)
  .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

## A Visual

Here's your original stream where c2 subscribes after two seconds

```html
src: 0-1-2-3-4
 c1: 0-1-2-3-4
 c2: ----2-3-4
```

and your stream where c2 subscribes right away and delays each emission 2 seconds

```html
src: 0-1-2-3-4
 c1: 0-1-2-3-4
 c2: ----0-1-2-3-4
```

## Sharing a Source

Sharing a source is not the same as having the same output.

Consider this:

```ts
const src = interval(1000).pipe(
  take(5),    
  map(x => x + 5),
  share()    
);

src.pipe(map(x => x - 1)).subscribe(console.log); // c1
src.pipe(map(x => x + 1)).subscribe(console.log); // c2
```

Output:

```html
src: 5-6-7-8-9
 c1: 4-5-6-7-8
 c2: 6-7-8-9-10
```

Even though they all have different outputs. `c1` and `c2` both have the same source. `c1` and `c2` don't generate any numbers, they just add 1 and subtract 1 from whatever numbers they're given. They transform their source.

This is the same thing you are doing in the second example. Instead of transforming the numbers, delay changes when an emission happens. `c2` emitted the same stream as the source, it just started emitting 2 seconds later and was still emitting 2 seconds after the source completed.

## Delay With setTimeout

```ts
const source = interval(1000).pipe(
  take(5),    
  share()
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log('c1', x));
source.subscribe(x =>
  setTimeout(_ => 
    console.log('c2', x), 
    2000
  )
);
```

## Wait before subscribing

```ts
const source = interval(1000).pipe(
  take(5),    
  share()
);
source.subscribe(x => console.log('c1', x));
timer(2000).pipe(
  switchMap(_ => source)
).subscribe(x => console.log('c2', x));
```

Comment: These answers have really helped me to have a deeper understanding of RXJS, Less magic more logic :-) Many thanks