# Why does a shared observable re-subscribe when the first one completes

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

When I run the code below I get the desired result followed by a re-subscription of the delayed shared observable when the other observable completes.

```
const source = interval(1000).pipe(
take(5),        
share());
source.subscribe(x => console.log('c1', x)); 

source.pipe(
  delay(2000),  // doesn't delay subscription buffers the output from interval observable
  switchMapTo(source)
```

).subscribe(x => console.log('c2', x));

output :
c1 0
c1 1
c1 2
c1 3
c2 3
c1 4
c2 4
c2 0
c2 1
c2 2
c2 3
c2 4

Comment: It looks like you've modified the code in the answer you got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67601577).  `source.pipe(delay(2000), switchMapTo(source))` is going to behave very, very differently compared to `of(null).pipe(delay(2000), switchMapTo(source))`.

Comment: Because the subscription that `delay` has to its source ends when the source completes: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/881cacdc99a7ebae219b595004c632f7358f730d/spec/operators/delay-spec.ts#L26-L28
And the `switchMapTo` happens _after_ that.

Answer (score 1):

This is recursive. `Source` emissions cause source subscriptions.

```ts
source.pipe(    // eventually "subscribes" to the source
  delay(2000),  // doesn't delay subscription buffers the output from interval observable
  switchMapTo(source) // subscribes again to the source after every emission
```

Maybe what you want is:

```ts
timer(2000).pipe( // eventually subscribes to a timer
  switchMapTo(source) // Subscribes to source after 2s (timer emits)
);
```